# Help in jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I want to do something like this:

```
var showLi = $("<li></li>");
$(showLi).append("<a href='#' class='showData'>Show</a>");
$($ul).append(showLi);
$(showLi+" a.showData").click(function(){
 alert("clicked");
});
```

the above code is giving error when I used the selector for adding **click** method.
What can be other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. showLi is not a string it's an object. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like so:

```
var showLi = $("<li></li>");
$("<a href='#' class='showData'>Show</a>").appendTo(showLi).click(function(){
     alert("clicked");
});
$ul.append(showLi);
```

This avoids searching the element again. `showLi` is already a jQuery object, so you should not pass it to `$()` again. By the naming of the variable `$ul` I assume that its value is a jQuery too. If this is not the case you indeed have to pass it to `$()`.

Alternatively, you can create the element with:

```
$('<a />', {href: '#', class: 'showData', text: 'Show'})
```

---

You get the error because you are trying to concatenate an object with a string. If you already have a jQuery object, then you can search for descendants with [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: Thanks Felix, but I wanted to know something other than find().

Comment: @Bhupi: You could also pass it as context as the others have shown `$('a.showData', showLi)`. But there are only these two possibilities if you are searching for descendants. Or you avoid searching at all as I have shown. But why wouldn't you want to use `find()`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use delegate() to bind the event handler, as it's not in the DOM upon page load. live() will also work, but delegate is more efficient.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/araqe3/edit

Comment: You don't *have to* use `delegate()` or `live()` but depending on the context of the code, this could be indeed an easier option.

Answer (score 1):

Use showLi as context:

```
$("a.showData",showLi).click([...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var showLi = $("<li></li>");
$(showLi).append("<a href='#' class='showData'>Show</a>");
$($ul).append(showLi)
$("a.showData", showLi).click(function(){
     alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var showLi = $("<li></li>");
    $(showLi).append("<a href='#' class='showData'>Show</a>");
    $('#test').append(showLi);
    $("a.showData").click(function(){
     alert("clicked");
    });
});
</script>
<div id='test'></div>
```